# Add dynamic value in spel expression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el, spring-integration-sftp

I have a string with constant value and I want to pass it to rename_to header while using MV gateway.

I have tried below code snippet and one by adding the variable in context and then using it with #basePath

```java
@Value("${basePath:/home/}")
String basePath;

.enrichHeaders(h -> h
                        .headerExpression(RENAME_TO, "'${basePath}' + headers[file_remoteFile]")
                        .headerExpression(REMOTE_FILE, "headers[file_remoteFile]")
                        .header(REMOTE_DIRECTORY, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]"))
```

I am getting error on startup. How can I give basePath in my application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `@Value("${basePath:/home/}")`
>
> `String basePath;`

Means "inject '/home/' into variable `basePath` if there is no `basePath` property.

You can't use fields from the enclosing class like that in the SPeL expression, and you can't use property placeholders in SpEL there; you have to concatenate the strings in the java.

```java
.headerExpression(RENAME_TO, "'" + this.basePath + "'" + " + headers[file_remoteFile]")
```

Comment: In short I want to place the basePath in my application.properties file instead of having it in class.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; I didn't realize you can't use property placeholders in those expressions. You need to do the concatenation in java.

Comment: Answer had one extra quote, I have removed that and it is working. Updated answer even.

Comment: @GaryRussell "you can't use property placeholders in SpEL there" is there a bug/feature request for enabling this? I just spent like two hours trying to get the correct combination of `#{}`, `${}` to get it to work just to find out it's not possible and I have to resort to string concatenation.

Comment: I don't believe so; feel free to open a new feature request here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues